# Git squash with recent commit taking precedence in conflicts

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution, squash

Say I have a series of commits after origin/master:

```
  5------4--------3-------2--------1
(master)                         (HEAD)
```

I want to squash 4 through 1 together into one commit, with the changes in 1 taking precedence in case of any conflict. Meaning the changes introduced in 1 will stay in the squash, and override any conflicts. (And if there are any new changes or files introduced in 4-2 which 1 does not conflict with, then those changes will stay)

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you [`git rebase --interactive`](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html) and `squash` commits 3-1?

Comment: But I don't want to have to manually resolve every conflict. I just want the changes introduced in my most recent commit "decide" the conflicts

Comment: Where would there be conflicts? The only way conflicts are introduced is when a commit is applied to a place where the code is different than when the commit was authored. During the rebase, commit 4 will only be applied to the codebase in it's post-5 state, and then 3 will be applied to the post-4 state. You're just getting rid of the milestones (4, 3, 2) in the middle.

Comment: Oh, they are already applied subsequently to that the change in one  commit overrides the change in the last commit.... exactly how I wanted... okay. Question can be closed.

I was afraid that if two commits changed the same line of code, a conflict would arise.

Comment: There could not possibly be any conflicts in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Use [`git rebase --interactive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to [squash the commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html).

Rebase steps are applied in commit sequence, and because you're using rebase only to adjust your work on its own ancestor, you don't give yourself any opportunity to introduce conflicts. Commit 4 will only be applied to the code in it's post-5 state, and then 3 will be applied to the post-4 state; you're just getting rid of the milestones (4, 3, 2) in the middle.

```
$ git rebase -i <commit-5>

pick <commit-4> This is commit 4
squash <commit-3> This is commit 3
squash <commit-2> This is commit 2
squash <commit-1> This is commit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `git rebase --interactive` (as suggested in comments) will work, but there's an easier way.

Before I refer you to it, though, I think it's appropriate here to note something very important about git: *every commit contains a complete snapshot of every file*.  Git does not store changes,<sup>1</sup> and in your diagram (which I'll re-label a bit):

```
... <- o <- A              <-- origin/master
             \
              B <- C <- D <- E   <-- HEAD=master
```

there are no deltas from `A` to `B`, `B` to `C`, and so on; instead, `A` gets you a complete source tree, as do `B` through `E`.  You might wonder, then, how it is that `git show` or `git log -p` can show you the change from `A` to `B`, `B` to `C`, and so on.  The answer is that git uses the parent-commit arrows—the shorter left-pointing `<-` arrows in the diagram—to find each commit's parent commit, and then git compares the two trees, constructing a diff on the fly for you, and giving that to you when you ask for it.  It's not stored in the repository, it's computed when you run `git show` or `git log -p`.

(The "arrow" from `B` to `A` is just `\` above because I can't draw an up-and-left-pointing arrow reliably, here.)

#### OK, but why should we care that each commit has a complete tree?

Mostly we don't *need* to care, but you said you wanted to squash commits `B` through `E` together so that you have just one single commit that has the source tree for `E`, with its parent commit being `A`.

Well, `E`, has the source tree for `E`.  So let's get it checked out as the current index/staging-area (from which the next commit will be made):

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

We're already there!  (If not, just check out the tip of the branch as usual.)

Now we need to make a new commit, using the current index, but having `A`, aka `origin/master`, as its parent commit.  We want this to be made on branch `master`, which is the current branch, but `master` currently points to commit `E`.  So let's re-set master to point to commit `A`, using `git reset`, but also instruct `git reset` to make no changes to the index (and no changes to the work tree):

```
$ git reset --soft origin/master
```

Now we have this as the diagram:

```
... <- o <- A              <-- origin/master, HEAD=master
             \
              B <- C <- D <- E   [to be abandoned]
```

Now let's make one new commit:

```
$ git commit
[enter commit message in editor as usual, write and quit editor]
$
```

This new commit—let's call it `F`—has the same *tree* as `E`, because when we did the `git reset` we left the index (and the work-tree) unchanged.  The `git commit` command always<sup>2</sup> makes the new commit based on the index.  So now we have this:

```
              F            <-- HEAD=master
             /
... <- o <- A              <-- origin/master
             \
              B <- C <- D <- E   [to be abandoned]
```

The "to be abandoned" sequence of commits is already invisible to `git log` (you must use git's reflogs, or raw SHA-1s, to find them) so we can stop drawing them entirely.  I left them in mainly for illustration: git almost always only ever adds *new* stuff.  Old stuff is left around.  The exception that makes it "almost always" is when git garbage-collects old stuff (older than the reflog expiration dates, normally 30 days for these commits).

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically this is a bit of an overstatement, because once you have enough "loose objects", git compresses them into "pack files", and "pack files" *do* use delta-compression, which stores changes.  The way git does this is quite unusual compared to most source control systems, though, and internally git extracts "packed" objects into "regular" (unpacked, not-delta-compressed) objects before even looking at their details, so it's reasonable to think about git's storage as "non-change-based".

<sup>2</sup>This too is overstatement: if you specify particular *files* to `git commit`, the commit command constructs the new commit without referring to the current index/staging-area.  (Internally it does this by using a new but temporary index, initialized from the `HEAD` commit.)

Comment: Note that with this method you'll need to write a new commit message representing the entirety of the change. With the `squash` command in `rebase -i` you'll be prompted with the messages of all squashed commits pre-populated in the editor, in order, for deletion or modification as needed.